# Merge node results into one MultilineString

Tags: geojson, overpass-api, mapbox-gl-js, turf, overpass-turbo

I'm trying to generate MultiLineStrings from street data nodes. Right now my workflow is as follows: I run something like the following through the Overpass Api, to get all the nodes:

```
[out:json][timeout:25];

{{geocodeArea:Berlin}}->.searchArea;

(
  node["highway"]["name"="Holteistraße"](area.searchArea);
  way["highway"]["name"="Holteistraße"](area.searchArea);
  relation["highway"]["name"="Holteistraße"](area.searchArea);

);
out body;
>;
out skel qt;
```

Then I export it as `geojson` and merge all `features` into one MultiLineString with `turf.js`. I then add this generated data as MultilineString into Mapbox.

I'm quite new to this, so this workflow probably isn't the best way to do it.

How could I directly call for a MultilineString via the overpass API?

Comment: That's not possible, Overpass API doesn't support GeoJSON output.

Comment: @mmd Do you plan to post it as an answer? (there is no chance for the other answer for "How could I directly call for a MultilineString via the overpass API?")

Comment: Maybe someone wants to suggest some alternative workflow. I can only answer the bit about Overpass API itself.

Comment: What do you mean exactly? The direct outpout from overpass? I can export as geojson over the website: overpass-turbo.eu